# Statement: For every real number $x$, if $x^4 + 4x^2 - 4x$ is less than zero, then x must be a number between 0 and 1

Tags: linear-algebra

I just want to double check if I got this question correct.

Statement: For every real number $x$, if $x^4 + 4x^2 - 4x$ is less than zero, then x must be a number between $0$ and $1$

a) Rewrite the given statement in symbolic form.

$$\forall x∈\mathbb{R},\ x^4 + 4x^2 - 4x < 0,\ 0 < x < 1$$

b) State the hypothesis of Statement 1.

$x^4 + 4x^2 - 4x$ is less than zero

c) State the conclusion of Statement 1.

$x$ must be a number between $0$ and $1$

d) State the negation of Statement 1 without using the word not or the ¬ symbol.

There exists a real number $x$, if $x^4 + 4x^2 - 4x$ is greater or equal to zero, then $x$ must be a number less than or equal to $0$ or greater than or equal to $1$.

If I did any of these wrong please let me know my mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only major problem I can see is in d). If your sentence starts with "there exists", then you should probably have a "such that" somewhere later. Remember that the negation of "For all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $P(x)\implies Q(x)$" is "There exists $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $P(x)$ but $\neg Q(x)$"; you shouldn't be negating the hypothesis.

In a), you might want to be a little bit more careful with the commas, so it's clear what is a hypothesis and what is a conclusion. Maybe something like

$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\ x^4-4x^2-4x<0\implies 0<x<1$$

or

$$(x\in\mathbb{R})\wedge(x^4-4x^2-4x<0)\implies 0<x<1.$$